# Destructor deleting memory premature

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, destructor, bigint

I am quiet new to memory management in C++. I made a BigInt class that is now fully implemented except for the destructor which is impacting performance of the program. However, when I try to implement the destructor my program crashes.

In the following code for multiplying BigInts:

```
BigInt& BigInt::operator*=(BigInt const& other) {

    //copy of this and other
    BigInt* tempThis = new BigInt(*this); //1st number
    BigInt* tempOther = new BigInt(other); //2nd number

    //create temps so we can use value of BigInt before it is changed
    BigInt* sum = new BigInt(0); //holds the eventual answer

    BigInt* i = new BigInt(0);

    //add *this BigInt to sum otherTemp amount of times
    //this will yield multiplication answer.
    for (*i; *i < *tempOther; *i = *i + 1) {
        *sum += *this;
    }

    *this = *sum;

    return *this;

}
```

The destructor is called when *i = *i + 1 is called in the for loop and then I think it gets deleted in my destructor which looks like this:

```
// destructor
BigInt::~BigInt() {
    delete[] this->bigIntVector;
}

// copy constructor
BigInt::BigInt(BigInt const& orig)
    : isPositive(orig.isPositive)
    , base(orig.base)
{
    this->bigIntVector = new BigIntVector(*(orig.bigIntVector));
}
```

Once 'i' is deleted nothing works and the whole program breaks.

If someone could give me a few pointers about destructors and how to fix my problem it would be great help. Thanks.

Comment: C++ is not Java.  That function is full of memory leaks.  Why are you using `new` in so many places (and not a single call to `delete`)?  Why not use the copy constructor (which you should have written) to create temporary BigInt's?

Comment: I thought I was using the copy constructor but I guess not. Do you have a suggestion for reformatting with less memory use?

Comment: For example, this: `BigInt* tempThis = new BigInt(*this); //1st number`  Should be this: `BigInt tempThis = *this;`  and also this: `BigInt sum(0);` instead of what you have now. If this doesn't work correctly, then you need to take a step back and implement the copy constructor correctly (and in addition, the assignment operator).

Comment: Also, your loop to multiply is flawed, unless you implemented an operator `+` for `BigInt` that takes an `int` argument.  The reason why it's flawed is that you won't be able to handle the case where you are multiplying by a BigInt that is greater than the max value of a regular `int` or `long` type.

Comment: I have implemented the neccessary '+' for that. If I change my code according to your suggestion will the destructor also work better or is that a seperate issue?

Comment: The destructor is fine.  There is nothing wrong with it.  What *is* wrong is that you didn't implement a correct copy constructor and assignment operator.  In other words the "rule of 3" needs to be adhered to.

Comment: I added my copy constructor, can you take a look and make sure I did that correctly?

Comment: whoops, I added the wrong one, I updated it with actual BigInt copy constructor

Comment: Where is the assignment operator?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: I do not implement that, I figured c++ covered that

Comment: No, it does not cover it.  If you want proof: `{ BigInteger b(10);  BigInteger b2(20); b = b2;}`  Try that, you will see double deletion errors and memory leaks when that `{ }` block is exited.

Comment: wow okay maybe I got my work cut out for me then. Thank you.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to learn the programming language you're trying to program in.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the same (horrible) arithmetic could be implemented as follows.

```
BigInt& BigInt::operator*=(BigInt const& other)
{
  if(other==0)
    return other;
  if(other> 1)
    for(BigInt old=*this,i=1; i!=other; ++i)
      operator+=old;
  else if(other<0) {
    BigInt old=*this;
    *this=0;
    for(BigInt i=0; i!=other; --i)
      operator-=old;
  }
  return*this;
}
```

assuming that the constructor from `int`, the copy constructor, the increment `operator++` and the addition `operator+=` are all properly implemented (as well as the destructor).

Unfortunately, you failed to give us more information, but your copy constructor and destructor are definitely broken:

```
this->bigIntVector = new BigIntVector(*(orig.bigIntVector));
```

is followed by

```
delete[] this->bigIntVector;
```

giving you undefined behaviour (allocating with `new` but deallocating with `delete[]` -- `delete[]` is for memory allocated with `new[]`). I suspect you meant to copy the memory from the original in the copy constructor. However, you don't. If

```
class BigInt {
  size_t    size=0;                // number of some_types allocated
  some_type*bigIntVector=nullptr;  // ptr to memory allocated, if any
  /* rest of class */
};
```

then the copy constructor could be implemented like (assuming `size` is non-static)

```
BigInt::BigInt(BigInt const&orig)
: size(orig.size()                                   // copy size
, bigIntVector(size? new some_type[size] : nullptr)  // allocate memory
{ std::memcpy(orig.bigIntVector, bigIntVector); }    // copy memory
```

However, (almost) the same could be implemented much easier with

```
class BigInt
{
  std::vector<some_type> bigIntVector;
public:
  BigInt(BigInt const&) = default;
  BigInt(BigInt &&) = default;
  BigInt&operator=(BigInt const&) = default;
  BigInt&operator=(BigInt &&) = default;
  / * rest of class */
};
```

when the copy and move constructors (as well as the respective assignment operators) are automatically *correctly* created for you. You only need to address the default constructor, for example

```
BigInt::BigInt()                    // default constructor
: bigIntVector(1,some_type(0)) {}   // size=1, value=0
```

and the constructors from built-in integer types. If you're new to C++, avoid `new` and `delete` in favour of standard library containers.

Comment: And once you stop being new to C++, avoid 99% or more of the places where you think of using `new` and `delete`,  typically in favour of standard containers ...